# Why does the Master Theorem work for this example but not the other?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

So apparently:

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n / \log n$ doesn't work with the Master Theorem because of the log term.

But then:

$T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n / \log n$ is $\Theta(n^2)$ even though it's still the same log term.

Why is this the case?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am asking about $n$ divided by $\log n$, not $n \log n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) lets one handle (many) recurrence relations of the form
$$
T(n) = aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + f(n)
$$
where $a\geq 1$ and $b > 1$. The key is to compare the function $f(n)$ to the quantity $\gamma\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \log_b a$.

In your two examples, $f(n)=\frac{n}{\log n}$; in the first case you have $a=b=2$ and $\gamma=1$. Therefore, $f(n)$ is **not** $O(n^c)$ for any $c< \gamma$, nor $\Theta(n^\gamma\log^k n)$ for any $k\geq 0$, nor $\Omega(n^c)$ for any $c>\gamma$: *none* of the 3 cases of the Master Theorem apply (although we are "pretty close" to the first). We cannot conclude, because the $\log n$ factor blurs the line between what part of the recurrence dominates: the overhead $f(n)$ at each step, or the branching factor (from one step to $a$ smaller substeps).

But in the second case, $a=4$, $b=2$, and thus $\gamma=2$. In this case, we **do** have $f(n) = O(n^c)$ for some $c < \gamma$ (taking $c=1$ works), and the first case of the Master theorem applies: we get $T(n) = \Theta(n^\gamma) = \Theta(n^2)$.

In a nutshell: the difference between the two cases you gave is not in $f(n)$, it is in the rest of the recurrence (the constant $a$), which allows the branching in the recurrence to dominate the complexity (each step gives rise to 4 substeps, not 2 as before, so they add up much more quickly.)

Comment: Also, and while this is not the original question, for completeness: the case above, not handled by the Master Theorem, can still be dealt with using the [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), or "manually" e.g. by studying $T^\prime(k) = \frac{T(2^k)}{2^k}$ instead. Both will lead to $T(n) = \Theta(n \log\log n)$ (i.e., $T^\prime(k) = \Theta(\log k)$, that is $T(2^k) = \Theta(2^k \log k))$).

Comment: Does Akra-Bazzi do everything the Master Theorem does?

Comment: Yes -- it is a strict generalization, iirc.

Comment: So far I've mostly been doing this with the Master Theorem: Compare $O(n^{\log_b(a)})$ with $O(f(n))$, ignoring any log factors, and see which one has the higher complexity (and that will be the answer), _unless_ they're the same, then the runtime is $f(n) \log n$. This seems to work for every case I've tried so far except for the ones I described above.

Comment: Is there an easy way to use Akra Bazzi?

Comment: Not that I know of, I use it quite rarely. Roughly, my advice would be: use the other, simpler theorems and methods, and try this one when they fail.

Comment: Is the method I outlined reasonable for most situations?